# testing my Ruby gem: undefined method `configure' for Shoulda::Matchers:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems, shoulda

I'm working on my first Ruby gem and have bundled cucumber, rspec and shoulda-matches for testing. When I run rspec, I get the following error:

```
/app/my_gem/spec/spec_helper.rb:6:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `configure' for Shoulda::Matchers:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Here is my gemspec:

```
# my_gem.gemspec
...
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  ...
  ...
  spec.add_development_dependency "activemodel"
  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.8"
  spec.add_development_dependency "cucumber"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 10.0"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rspec" 
  spec.add_development_dependency "shoulda-matchers"
end
```

My `spec_helper.rb`:

```
require 'my_gem'
require 'pry'
require 'shoulda/matchers'

Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec

    # with.library :active_record
    with.library :active_model
    # with.library :action_controller
    # Or, choose all of the above:
    # with.library :rails
  end
end
```

It's finding Shoulda::Matchers but not the `.configure` method for some reason. Am I requiring `shoulda` wrong somehow? Not sure if this is related, but the rspec is also giving me this warning:

```
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
  json (>= 1.7.7, ~> 1.7)
  minitest (~> 5.1)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
```

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use the documentation for the 3.0.0.alpha version of shoulda-matchers which supports `3.0.0.alpha`, but are using an older version. Either see the correct documentation for the version you are using (I'm guessing [2.8.x](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/tree/v2.8.0#shoulda-matchers---)) or update your Gemfile to use `3.0.0.alpha`:

```
gem 'shoulda-matchers', github: 'thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers'
```

Then run `bundle install` and `Shoulda::Matchers.configure` should start working.

Comment: Thanks, you were exactly right. I am using 2.8.0 and the configure block isn't necessary

Comment: it is misspell, took me a while to figure out an error while running bundle install

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by @infused is correct.

The documentation and configuration provided in GitHub is for version 3.x and not for 2.x.

In order to make it work, **change the version of should-matchers to '~> 3.0.0.alpha' and then run 'bundle update should-matchers'**

Answer (score -1):

Git protocol is depreciated, now use:

```
   gem 'shoulda-matchers', git: 'https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers.git'
```

(per https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/719#issuecomment-103556439)